# HTML5 Geolocation fails on https site

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications, geolocation

Due to recent changes on Chrome 50 that requires https for html5 geolocation we have recommended that one of our customers migrate their site to https. They currently have both the http and the https active. We currently can still obtain location on the http site but it does not work on the https site. Is there something different that needs to happen in code, on the server, or on the device to obtain GPS coordinates on an https site?

The customer is using Android Samsung Galaxy S6 on the standard "Internet" browser.

The code that I'm using is very simple. Nothing at all fancy.

```
function success(position)
        {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';
}

function error(error)
        {
            output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location" + error.code + " - " + error.message
        };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

Comment: Check that all of the libraries such as any javascript libraries that are imported during page load is using an https address. If the url for the import is not https, the page will be considered only partially trusted, and that may cause a problem like you are having. In Firefox, the lock on the url bar for the certificate will have a gray mark. Chrome does not show that (my version)

Comment: That's it, I was calling $.getScript on an external http javascript file earlier in the page. I downloaded the script and included it in my script directory and that fixed the problem.  I'll gladly accept your answer if you copy it into the answer section. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using https, all links to or downloads of external scripts for the page must use https or the page will be considered "partially trusted". In later versions of Firefox, if this is the case, you will see a grey symbol along with the normal lock symbol in the location bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make calls to http from https, but you can get the latitude and longitude data from **https://freegeoip.net/json/**